# Prove SubsetSum is polyequivalent to SubsetSum with surplus

Tags: subset-sum, polynomial-time-reductions

I'm solving problem 13.17 of [What can be computed?](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691170664/what-can-be-computed), which is asking to prove $\text{SubsetSum} \equiv_{P} \text{SubsetSumWithFives}$.
Here is the definition of SubsetSumWithFives.

> SUBSETSUMWITHFIVES: it is identical to the decision variant of SUBSETSUM, except that we may use up to 10 extra packages with weight 5 when constructing the desired subset.

I thought I could show $\text{SubsetSumWithFives} \le_{P} \text{SubsetSum}$ by adding 10 extra 5 weights.
However, I have no idea to show $\text{SubsetSum}\le_{P} \text{SubsetSumWithFives}$

Is there any suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the Subset Sum instance by multiplying all the weights of the "packages" and the target weight by 51.

Notice how, in the modified instance, adding any additional weight between 0 and 50 cannot change whether the target weight can be attained.
If up to 10 packages with weight 5 were available, then you could only add weights up to 50. Therefore this modified instance can be immediately thought as an instance of Subset Sum with Fives.